# How can I read from a file in c until a character is reached?

Tags: arrays, c, file, character, 2d

```
sara,fahmi,sarafah@yahoo.fr,secret5648,UIR,undergrad,Rabat,UK,what is my favourite color?,blue,400246212432285,418,03/21/2023
```

I want to store this line in different arrays. For example store sara in first name, fahmi in last name...

Comment: Use `strtok()` to split the string at comma characters.

Comment: Read the whole line into a string, then use string functions.

Comment: Before using the function [`strtok`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtok), you will have to use the function [`fgets`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets) to read a line of input.